# How to copy folder structure and all files except one file type

Tags: windows-10

I need to burn Blu-rays discs with files for backup. My files are all image files .JPG .DNG .MOV etc nested in numerous folders and subfolders. I do not want to copy the DNG files (because I have a JPG copy and the DNGs are so big). Is there anyway to create a filter so that I copy all files and the folder structure but excluding the DNGs?.
I'm on Windows 10, and sorry I haven't learned wine yet

Comment: How are you currently copying the files? I have some ideas but wonder how you are doing this currently exactly?

Comment: I use TeraCopy to copy all files and folders to another drive, and they run a search for all *.dngs and delete them. But this is taking a long time and I'm running out of space

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Open a PowerShell session (or cmd.exe) and run something like this:

```
robocopy.exe sourceLocation TargetLocation /S /XF *.dng
```

The `/XF` switch will exclude all *.dng files from the copy operation.

Comment: Thank you, that is looking like what I am after. I usually use TeraCopy to copy files, as it has a verify function where it checks the original against the copy using checksums. Is there a switch in Robocopy I can use to verify copies as well? I have looked but can't see one and it would be really useful to check the integrity of the backups.

Comment: I don't know about a verify option in Robocopy, but I never ever had problems with corrupt files when using Robocopy. The nice thing about Robocopy is that it is part of Windows itself. Doesn't TeraCopy have a /XF switch?

Comment: @bluefin Another idea may be to allow Robocopy to do the copy process and then set Veracopy to do a comparison of the source and destination afterwards for the checksum or whatever if it can do so. It seems Teracopy has unlocked functionality with the paid pro version so consider checking to see if the pro version has the feature you need to exclude. Otherwise, you Robocopy for the copy with exclusion and another process to compare file checksums afterwards.

Comment: Hi Peter, I have asked a question to Teracopy to see if they have a /XF switch, that would cover it. 
I presume you meant Teracopy instead of Veracopy in your comment? if so i you can't really just verify / compare with teracopy unless all filenames are the same on the source and the destination.

Comment: Hi Peter, Thanks for your answers . I have asked a question to Teracopy to see if they have a /XF switch, that would cover it. 
I presume you meant Teracopy instead of Veracopy in your 2nd comment? if so, i you can't really just verify / compare with teracopy unless all filenames are the same on the source and the destination. Are there any other verify programs you know?

Comment: I use PowerShell's Get-FileHash to make sure two files are the same, but that may be slow for large files or many files. Never use Veracopy but I am sure there are many tools that allow file verification.

Comment: Hi Peter, thanks again, yours is the only solution I have heard of that works. 
If/when I get a response back from TeraCopy I will put it here as I'm guessing I'm not the only one who would find it useful to be have a verified way of copying large amounts of certain files for tasks such as Backups. Thanks again.

Comment: Info: If you need to exclude multiple file types, just write them all down after /XF separated by spaces e.g. /XF *.type1 *.type2